# How to boot tablet from usb

Tags: shell, windows, uefi

I need to boot my tablet from usb stick where my `windows 10` install files are stored. There are no boot settings, I can access only `UEFI shell` see:
[image: My picture]

That usb is blk0 and blk1 (when i unplug they dissapear). I tried to use `mount` command with no success. Also tried `bcfg`command: `bcfg mv 2 0`. `EFI Usb device` is now in priority 0, but after restart system still boots windows from internal drive. Also DevPath is empty for `EFI Usb device`. How can I boot from USB?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Unix or Linux.

Comment: What kind of tablet?  How were the Windows 10 files installed to the USB stick?  How was the USB stick prepared (e.g. during formatting)?

Comment: If you can't turn off Secure Boot on the tablet, try using [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) to make the flash drive bootable.  It has an option for EFI.

Comment: @fixer1234 Depending on his answers to the questions I gave, there may be better options than Rufus.